# Does piping mysqldump -h sourceRemote | mysql -h targetRemote proxy through my local machine?

Tags: mysql, pipe

Due to some limitations on the remote servers, I am I'm executing something along the lines of the following from my local machine: `mysqldump -h sourceRemote | mysql -h targetRemote`.

My question is, does the pipe require that the mysqldump data pass through my local machine first, or does it put the two servers in direct communication so that my local machine is not a bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

The shell pipe operator necessarily pulls the data through your machine. If you were connecting them some other way it wouldn't be with the pipe involved.